# Hadoop namenode is not starting CDH4.7

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

After newly installed hadoop from CDH4.7 in Mint-17(Linux) operating system the namenode is not starting, but secondary-namenode, tasktracker, jobtracker and datanode are started.

Here is the related informations

**/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <!-- Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in. 
       On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.  -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.safemode.extension</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
     <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/namesecondary</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data</value>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
  <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hadoop-hdfs/dn._PORT</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader.local</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm</name>
   <value>750</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.block.local-path-access.user</name>
   <value>impala</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>classic</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf**

```
total 88
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2998 May 28 22:57 capacity-scheduler.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 1335 May 28 22:57 configuration.xsl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    233 May 28 22:57 container-executor.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 1002 Sep 25 19:29 core-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 1774 May 28 22:57 hadoop-metrics2.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2490 May 28 22:57 hadoop-metrics.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 9196 May 28 22:57 hadoop-policy.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2802 Sep 27 18:20 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 8735 May 28 22:57 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4113 May 28 22:57 mapred-queues.xml.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1097 Sep 25 19:34 mapred-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    178 May 28 22:57 mapred-site.xml.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop   10 May 28 22:57 slaves
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2316 May 28 22:57 ssl-client.xml.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2251 May 28 22:57 ssl-server.xml.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2513 May 28 22:57 yarn-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2262 May 28 22:57 yarn-site.xml
```

**sudo hadoop namenode -format**

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/09/27 18:44:16 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = surendhar/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.0.0-cdh4.7.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/cloudera-jets3t-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-test-hadoop2-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-format-1.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-avro-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-scrooge-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-bundle-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-encoding-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-bundle-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hive-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-common-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-cascading-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-pig-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-thrift-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-sources.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-hadoop-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-generator-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0-javadoc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//parquet-column-1.2.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/cloudera-jets3t-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/avro-compiler-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//hadoop-core.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://localhost/data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-ubuntu64-10-04/CDH4.7.0-Packaging-Hadoop-2014-05-28_09-36-51/hadoop-2.0.0+1604-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.17~lucid/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8; compiled by 'jenkins' on Wed May 28 10:11:49 PDT 2014
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_55
************************************************************/
14/09/27 18:44:16 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Formatting using clusterid: CID-61d4b942-4b4f-4693-a4c5-6bc3cce2a408
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.HeartbeatManager: Setting heartbeat recheck interval to 30000 since dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval is less than dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
14/09/27 18:44:17 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 0
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO namenode.NNStorage: Storage directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file of size 119 saved in 0 seconds.
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/09/27 18:44:21 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at surendhar/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

**sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start**

```
 * Starting Hadoop namenode: 
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-surendhar.out
```

**sudo jps**

```
3131 Bootstrap
6321 Jps
```

**cat /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-surendhar.out**

```
ulimit -a for user hdfs
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30083
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30083
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**sudo ls -lR /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache**

```
/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 hdfs      hdfs      4096 Sep 25 19:39 hdfs
drwxrwxr-x 3 mapred    mapred    4096 Sep 25 19:39 mapred
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root      4096 Sep 25 19:44 root
drwxr-xr-x 3 surendhar surendhar 4096 Sep 25 19:35 surendhar

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 4 hdfs hdfs 4096 Sep 25 19:39 dfs

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs:
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 hdfs hdfs 4096 Sep 25 19:39 data
drwxrwxr-x 2 hdfs hdfs 4096 Sep 27 18:18 namesecondary

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/namesecondary:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 25 19:39 mapred

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 7 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 27 18:12 local

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 27 18:12 taskTracker
drwxrwxr-x 2 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 27 18:12 toBeDeleted
drwxr-xr-x 2 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 27 18:12 tt_log_tmp
drwx------ 2 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 27 18:12 ttprivate
drwxr-xr-x 2 mapred mapred 4096 Sep 25 19:40 userlogs

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/taskTracker:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/toBeDeleted:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/tt_log_tmp:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/ttprivate:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/userlogs:
total 0

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 25 19:44 dfs

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 27 18:44 name

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs/name:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 27 18:44 current

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/root/dfs/name/current:
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Sep 27 18:44 fsimage_0000000000000000000
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62 Sep 27 18:44 fsimage_0000000000000000000.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2 Sep 27 18:44 seen_txid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201 Sep 27 18:44 VERSION

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/surendhar:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 surendhar surendhar 4096 Sep 25 19:35 dfs

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/surendhar/dfs:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 surendhar surendhar 4096 Sep 25 19:35 name

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/surendhar/dfs/name:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 surendhar surendhar 4096 Sep 25 19:35 current

/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/surendhar/dfs/name/current:
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 surendhar surendhar 124 Sep 25 19:35 fsimage_0000000000000000000
-rw-r--r-- 1 surendhar surendhar  62 Sep 25 19:35 fsimage_0000000000000000000.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 surendhar surendhar   2 Sep 25 19:35 seen_txid
-rw-r--r-- 1 surendhar surendhar 201 Sep 25 19:35 VERSION
```

Comment: do hadoop namenode and post the log

Comment: what is the error you are getting. Make sure nothing else is bind to the port 50070

Answer (score 0):

Here error is not clear, it could be because of permission, xml validations, etc.

You better use hadoop command to start namenode, instead of using `service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start`  command. The advantage is that you will get the error message in the console itself. No need to go and check you namenode log files. Execute the below command and post the logs you are getting in the console.

```
sudo hadoop namenode
```

---

Looks like because of some issues, you are not able to start namenode using hdfs command. 
When you execute the /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode script, which internally invokes in the following script `/usr/lib/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh` for starting hadoop daemons.

As a workaround you might need to change the line 151 ( `nohup nice -n $HADOOP_NICENESS $hdfsScript --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &` ) in the file `/usr/lib/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh`  as follows

```
nohup nice -n $HADOOP_NICENESS $hadoopScript --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Above command uses $hadoopScript instead of $hdfsScript env variable.

Comment: That is what I tried after that, and which fixed the issue. But for longer run, I want to use "service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start".
Any idea?

Comment: What is  the error you are getting while executing the command "sudo hdfs namenode"

Comment: nothing gets display. But namenode is not starting.

Comment: Modified the answer. Try modify the files /usr/lib/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh as mentioned in the modified answer